# height map brings weird result

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement, height-map

I have a height map (grayscale mode).
[image]

It looks nice but it gives very bad result when i plug in it in displacement either bump node. 
[image]

Actually i can zoom out and i won't see this but i need to bake normals with this displacement...

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem with your provided image. works fine for me (you'll always get some artifacts with an 8 Bit Jpeg though). May be you could upload your .blend so we can have a look what wrong?

Comment: I don't know how to attach anything in comment.... Also i don't understand how to attach .blend file in discussion.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because of two things:

1. Your image is a highly compressed JPG, creating banding issues and artifacts which get amplified by using it as a bump map.
   I would suggest using a PNG with a higher bitrate.
2. You set the bump strength to 3, which makes the color data clip. 0-1 is the safe margin if you have 100% black in your image (which you do). I suggest working with the distance value instead if you want to have a more pronounced depth effect.

Comment: I guess the problem is in image. If we zoom attached image we can see these "layers" of pixels that aren't smooted. Maybe its because of compression but i don't have another image.
Also i have to set bump strength more than 1 to get the desired result.
I solved this problem by recreating new bump map with this one. (i used it as displacement map on plane in zbrush, then smooth it, then bake again. Then it began to work properly.